# Stotra/Stuti from scriptures that confers same benefit as performing an agnihotra

Tags: stotra, agni, homam

I heard that there are some stotras or stutis in Mahabharata that have phala shruti in them which says that reciting that particular set of verses confers equivalent benefit as having done agnihotra rite. However, I have looked up Vyasa Mahabharata and I could not find any such stotras or stutis.

So is there any such stotra or stuti to Agni or Vishnu/Shiva/Devi or Indra etc. anywhere in our Puranas or even Vedas that give such phalashruti?